# Is it possible to embed a flash player in a table and retain the table properties

Tags: html, flash, html-table, embed

I'd like to embed a music (flash) player in a table with clickable images but the embed code seems to throw the table properties off - it extends the width of the table.

Is it possible to embed the player on the same row as the image whilst still retaining the table width?

Here's what I've been using:

```
<table width="620"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div align="left">
            <object height="18" width="100%"> 
                <param name="movie" value="https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F1253725&amp;auto_play=false&amp;player_type=tiny&amp;font=Georgia&amp;color=9a6600&show_playcount=false&default_width=375&default_height=40&show_user=false"></param> 
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param> 
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
                <embed wmode="transparent" allowscriptaccess="always" height="18" src="https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F1253725&amp;auto_play=false&amp;player_type=tiny&amp;font=Georgia&amp;color=9a6600&show_playcount=false&default_width=375&default_height=40&show_user=false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed> 
            </object>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div align="right"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31856944/Virb/splash_freedownload-2.png" border="0" width="245" height="42" usemap="#Map" /></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div align="right"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31856944/Virb/splash_share-2.png" border="0" width="620" height="31" usemap="#Map2" /></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first row (`<tr>`) you have two cells, in second row there is just one cell.
Additionally, in the first row, first cell the `div` has no closing tag.

Try fixing this error first and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="620"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div style="{ width: 300px; height: 200px; }">
            <object height="18" width="80%"> 
                <param name="movie" value="https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F1253725&amp;auto_play=false&amp;player_type=tiny&amp;font=Georgia&amp;color=9a6600&show_playcount=false&default_width=375&default_height=40&show_user=false"></param> 
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param> 
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
                <embed wmode="transparent" allowscriptaccess="always" height="18" src="https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F1253725&amp;auto_play=false&amp;player_type=tiny&amp;font=Georgia&amp;color=9a6600&show_playcount=false&default_width=375&default_height=40&show_user=false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed> 
            </object>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div align="right"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31856944/Virb/splash_freedownload-2.png" border="0" width="245" height="42" usemap="#Map" /></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div align="right"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31856944/Virb/splash_share-2.png" border="0" width="620" height="31" usemap="#Map2" /></div>
        </td>
        <td>empty</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

is working ...

- close all open tags
- use same column number for each row

Comment: This didn't work for me as it placed the player in a new row.